# Add filename of imported file to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Still pretty new to Python so please be patient. I have a directory of files, all with a similar naming scheme. The filename look like this:

yob2004.txt
yob2005.txt

What I am trying to do is open each one of those files and add to a dataframe. Then I want to extract the year from the filename and add that as a new column in the dataframe.

I can get parts of it but not the whole thing.

Here is the year extraction code for  the year from the filename.

```
filenames = glob.glob('names/*.txt')

#split off the beginning of of he file path plus 'yob' and only keep 
everything after that. ex. 1180.txt
split1 = [i.split('\yob', 1)[1] for i in filenames]

#split of the .txt from the strings in the list above
split2 = [i.split('.', 1)[0] for i in split1]
```

Here is the code to concatenate all of the files together

```
read_files = glob.glob("names/*.txt")

with open("allnames.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

I'm thinking what I actually need to do is read the first file into a dataframe then extract the year from the filename and write that to a new column in the dataframe. Then move onto the next file. Rinse. Repeat.

Any guidance how to do this?

Comment: what do the contents of the file look like? If it is multiline then you would have to add the year to each row corresponding to the contents of the file.

Comment: So there are several rows with a name, sex and count. Looks like this: Mary,F,7065

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for your data, suppose I have 2 files yob2004.txt and yob2005.txt:

```
#yob2004
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
5,6,7,8

#yob2005
8,9,10,11
a,b,c,d
f,j,k
i,j,k,l
```

We see that these files have different data types, and different numbers of rows/columns so most edge cases will be covered:

```
import pandas as pd
from os import walk

f = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk('/home/dkennetz/yobDf'):
    for x in filenames:
        if x.startswith('yob'):
            f.append(x)
#f = ['yob2005.txt', 'yob2004.txt'] created a list from filenames in directory ^^^

data = pd.DataFrame() # initialize empty df
for filename in f:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']) # read in each csv to df
    df['filename'] = filename # add a column with the filename
    data = data.append(df) # add all small df's to big df 

data['filename'] = data['filename'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('yob').rstrip('.txt')) # get rid of yob and .txt and just keep year
print(data)
```

output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 filename
0    8    9   10   11     2005
1    a    b    c    d     2005
2    f    j    k  NaN     2005
3    i    j    k    l     2005
0    1    2    3    4     2004
1    2    3    4    5     2004
2    5    6    7    8     2004
```

The output will tell which file it came from by placing the year next to column and NAN's where dfs are different sizes.